# Laravel Query not returning any data

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a database table 'mileages' which contains 3 columns :

```
start_location 
end_location
miles
```

My query is built using a scope selector in my Mileage model (start_location and end_location are getting passed in appropriately):

```
//Get miles for the start_location -> end_location

public function scopeMileageDistance($query)
{
    return $query->where('start_location', '=', 'start_location')->where('end_location', '=', 'end_location');
}

//THIS ONE WORKS
//Get a list of the locations from the DB
public function scopeMileageLocations($query)
{
    return $query->select('start_location')->groupBy('start_location');
}
```

I'm accessing it in my Controller the same way I access my locations query (which works):

```
//WORKS
$locations = Mileage::MileageLocations()->get();
//DOES NOT WORK
$distance = Mileage::MileageDistance()->get();
```

When I dumpordie:

```
dd($distance);
```

It shows as returning nothing.  But if I run this SQL query on the database - it gets back the appropriate object:

```
select * from mileages where start_location = 'pointA' and end_location = 'pointB'
```

I am accessing this from an Ajax call which is fired when the user makes a dropdown selection:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'created',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, start_location:start_location.value, end_location:end_location.value},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
                $("#result").append(JSON.stringify(data));
                return data;
            }
        });
```

Just wondering if I'm doing something wrong with my scope selector and/or query.

Comment: you have to use ``return`` in your scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because you need to pass some parameter to your function:

```
public function scopeMileageDistance($query, $start, $end)
{
    $query->where('start_location', '=', $start)->where('end_location', '=', $end)->get();
}
```

So, you could use It with something like this:

```
$start = $request->get($start_location);
$end = $request->get($end_location);
...
        ->scopeMileageDistance($start, $end);
...
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the Builder

```
public function scopeMileageDistance($query)
{
    return $query->where('start_location', '=','start_location')
    ->where('end_location', '=', 'end_location');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `get()` from your scope and add `return`.

```
public function scopeMileageDistance($query)
{
    return $query->whereStartLocation('start_location')->whereEndLocation('end_location');
}
```

The thing is you don't return anything from the scope, that's why you get empty result.

Comment: Still not working. Perhaps it's something with my ajax.

Comment: Maybe, but still to find an error you should use this code (with `return` and without `get()`).

Comment: I've updated my code - and updated my question to reflect it.  I appreciate the input!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the `where` parameter in your query:

I'm talking about the pointA & pointB

And you need to return the query

```
return $query->where('start_location', '=', 'pointA')->where('end_location', '=', 'pointB')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function scopeMileageDistance($query)
{
    return $query->whereStartLocation('start_location')->whereEndLocation('end_location');
}
```

Comment: Still not working. Perhaps it's something with my ajax.